# How to create n strings of random lengths the sum of which is equal to a given amount?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, random

I'm trying to create an algorithm to create `n` strings of random length the sum of which is equal to a given amount.

An example to make it clearer:

```
total = 20;
n = 7;

strings = ['aaaa', 'a', 'aaaaaaa', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aa', 'a'];
```

So I have 7 strings of random lengths and the sum of their individual lengths is (unless I made an error counting) 20.

Till now I came up with this recursive function:

```
gaps = [];
function createGapsArray(total, n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        var gapLength = total;
    } else {
        var gapLength = getRandomInt(1, total / 2);
    }

  var gap = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < gapLength; i++) {
    gap += "a";
  }
  gaps.push(gap);

  if (n > 1 && total > 0) {
    createGapsArray(total - gapLength, --n);
  }
}
```

Which doesn't really work. Usually it finishes before generating all the n segments I want. With the few tests that I've done, it seems that dividing the total by 4 instead of 2, gets the job done. Like:

```
var gapLength = getRandomInt(1, total / 4);
```

But the choice of this constraint is just arbitrary. I'm wondering if there is a better approach to this.

Also, I'm aware that with my approach the algorithm is likely to generate longer segments at first and smaller ones towards the end. I wouldn't mind an even distribution, but it's not a big deal because for what I need it I can simply shuffle the array once it's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a similar problem to "find a random collection of k numbers whose sum is N". The original version of this answer used a simple solution which is unbiased if the numbers are continuous (i.e. floating point): generate k-1 numbers in the range `[0, N]`, sort them, put 0 at the beginning and N at the end, and then find the differences between successive elements. But since there are no fractional characters, we need the numbers to be integers and the above algorithm is biased against collections which include 0 (there is an infinitesimal probability of getting 0 in the continuous case, but it is significant in the discrete case).

An unbiased solution for generating non-empty integer solutions is to find a random (k-1)-combination of the integers in the inclusive range [1, N-1]. To find the random combination use the first k-1 elements of a random shuffle of the range (using the Fisher-Yates shuffle). The combination is then sorted (if necessary) and a 0 prepended; these values are the starting positions of each string (so that the next value is the ending position.)

That will not produce empty substrings, since each substring has a unique starting point. To include empty substrings, use the above  with N+k instead of N, and then shrink every range by 1: if the indices are sorted, you can do that by subtracting *i* from the *i*<sup>th</sup> index.

In Python:

```
from random import sample
def random_split(str, k):
    v = [0] + sorted(sample(range(1, len(str)), k-1)) + [len(str)]
    return [str[v[i]:v[i+1]] for i in range(k)]

def random_split_allow_empty(str, k):
    v = [0] + sorted(sample(range(1, len(str)+k), k-1)) + [len(str)+k]
        return [str[v[i]-i:v[i+1]-i-1] for i in range(k)]
```

In Javascript:

```
function shuffle(vec, k) {
  for (let i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    let r = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (vec.length - i));
    let t = vec[r];
    vec[r] = vec[i];
    vec[i] = t;
  }
  return vec;
}

function random_partition(N, k) {
  let v = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < N; ++i) v[i-1] = i;
  shuffle(v, k - 1);
  v[k-1] = 0;
  return v.slice(0, k).sort((a,b)=>a-b);
}

function random_split(s, k) {
  return random_partition(s.length, k).map(
    (v, i, a) => s.slice(v, a[i+1]));
}

function random_split_allow_empty(s, k) {
  return random_partition(s.length + k, k).map((v,i)=>v-i).map(
    (v, i, a) => s.slice(v, a[i+1]));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I'll take the time to try it out. Thanks also for writing it in javascript as well

Comment: this is definitely the most complete solution so I'll accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, you can't do this, because you're adding constraints to at least the last "string" that violate the desired randomness property. Of course, how strictly you need to interpret the requirement for randomness depends largely on what you're doing in the bigger problem domain.

What you could do instead, is start with an initial string of the desired length, and then iteratively generate a random split point until you have the desired number of fragments. To be truly random, you'd have to allow for some of those fragments to be empty (e.g. what happens if you randomly pick a single-character fragment to split?), but that could probably be worked around without doing too much violence to the randomness of the overall result...

Comment: For non-empty strings, you can start with a string of length `total-n`, do the same as you would for empty strings, but then just add a character to each string at the end.

Comment: I'm not really interested in true randomness. Your approach is interesting, but how would you proceed with the splittings? What if at the first split I get a string long n-1? Shall I always go on splitting the longest segment?

Comment: Start by putting the initial string in a list. On each iteration, select one string randomly from the list (call it `x`), generate a random number between 0 and `len(x) - 1` (optionally between 1 and `len(x) - 2` to avoid creating empty strings), split the string at that position, and replace it with the two pieces. Iterate until you have the target number of fragments. Add appropriate tests to avoid splitting single-character strings if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The way to think of it is as having string of characters of length equal to total. I'll use 20 as an example:

```
string: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
index:  01234567890123456789
```

You then generate N-1 random numbers between `0` and `total` that correspond to the positions that you should cut the string to generate N different strings.

Lets say the numbers are 5, 8, 13, 15, 1, 3. These will be the indices to cut the string:

```
string: a aa aa aaa aaaaa aa aaaaa
index:  0|12|34|567|89012|34|56789
```

This is the same as generating N-1 random numbers, sorting them, adding `0` at the beginning of the list and `total` at the end, and taking the difference:

```
var numbers = [0];
for (var i = 0; i < N-1; i++) numbers.push(getRandomInt(0, total));
numbers.push(total);
numbers.sort();

var strings = [];
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
  strings.push(new Array(numbers[i + 1] - numbers[i]).join('a'));
```

This will give a uniform distribution.

Note that if you want only non-empty strings there should be no duplicate random values.